# How do I check if queryset is empty for multiple objects in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So, my template is receiving an object that has generic foreign key relations with 3 other models and now I need to check if all three of these exist or not to show the user a custom message based on what exists and doesn't exist.

Here's some perspective:
Person Object has 3 different models attached to it:

1. Address
2. Email
3. Phone

If all 3 don't exist, then I want the template to say
`No contact details found, you may add new contact info"

But, even if either of the three exist, then don't show the message. I tried this:

```
{% if person.address.all and person.email.all and person.phone.all %}
    <!-- Do something here to show the details of each object -->

{% else %}
    <!-- Show the default message -->

{% endif %}
```

But what happens here is that if Address exists, but Phone and Email do not, it'll show the message - which is not what I want. How do I achieve my desired result? Can I check for Null?

Comment: try: if person.address.all or person.email.all or person.phone.all

Comment: That works! If you can put it as answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'or' instead of 'and'. If you use 'and', it will return true only when each of email&phone&address have at least one record.

Please refer the link for better understanding 'and' and 'or'.
[The Peculiar Nature of and and or](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html)

```
{% if person.address.all or person.email.all or person.phone.all %}
    <!-- Do something here to show the details of each object -->

{% else %}
    <!-- Show the default message -->

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a property and using it in the template, to avoid placing so much logic in the template:

In the model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def has_contact_details(self):
        return self.address.exists() or self.email.exists() or person.phone.exists()
```

In the template:

```
{% if person.has_contact_details %}
    <!-- Do something here to show the details of each object -->

{% else %}
    <!-- Show the default message -->

{% endif %}
```